# Wait for a function with an async operation to finish

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

How can I wait for a function that itself has an async operation to finish?

*Let me give you an example:*

`Function_A` fetches a photo from gallery. Fetching operation will be executed asynchronously using fetching closure.

I call `Function_A` in `Function_B` and I want to wait the photo fetching operation to finish, and after that continue my code.

*What I've tried:*

I've used dispatch group but it has not worked. I've also tried to call `Function_A` in a sync block, and this was unsuccessful too.

How can I wait for this operation to finish? Can be this problem because of running fetching operation into another queue?

**Update**:

This is what I did:

```
class imageFetch: NSObject{
    var theImage: PHAsset? = nil
    func Function_A(){
        let fetchOption = PHFetchOptions()         
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (authStatus) in
            // It seems code will be executed asynchronously from here
            if authStatus == .authorized{
                let imageAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOption)
            // Select image and save it in theImage
            // I know I can send a closure and run it here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in another class I call that  function:

```
class edit: NSObject{
    funct Function_B(){
        var imageFetchIns = imageFetch()
        // I want below code to execute asynchronously
        imageFetchIns.Function_A()

        // Now I want to wait last operation to finish
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into promise libraries?

Comment: not sure why dispatchgroup wouldn't work. Try showing code with it.

Comment: Also RxSwift will solve the task easily

Comment: Is `PHAsset` your code?

Comment: I used PHAsset to store my selected image. It's not my problem. The problem is where I commented in code as ```wait last operation to finish```.

Answer (score 1):

Without code is quite difficult to understand what is going on. If you take a look to [Using dispatch groups to wait for multiple web services](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) you will find what is going on.

Otherwise you can start using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`. In fact, if you have two operations, you can add a dependency between them. In other words, you can say that an operation can start only after the one it depends on has finished is execution. In addition to that, an operation has also the benefits to be cancellable. Useful when you want to deal with user actions, for example.
[NSOperation and NSOperationQueue Tutorial in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) will give you a very good intro on how to use them.

What I would like to stress out with operations is that an operation (especially when you subclass it) represents a self-contained task that can be reusable - in your project or in different projects as well.